# Прижатие футера к низу

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Практикуют ли в наше время такое "прижатие" футера

```
content{min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);}
```

Или все же лучше старое ?

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В наше время функция *calc()* не очень распространена, она не работает в старых браузерах, например я очень редко встречал такую функцию, большинство пользуются старым и проверенным кодом css [**4 способа прижать футер**](http://dimox.name/press_footer_bottom_with_css/),
таблица в каких браузерах работает функция *calc()* [**ссылка на сайт**](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).